# Why is `go get <module@version>` downgrading other packages?

Tags: go

I'm trying to upgrade particular module by running `go get themodule@latest` and, while it is working to upgrade the `themodule` module version, it is also downgrading a couple other modules that are in my go.mod / go.sum. Why is this happening? Thanks!

I tried `go get themodule@latest` and it downgraded a couple other modules in addition to upgrading `themodule`.

Comment: Probably because of version dependency of the module you are upgrading.

Comment: @accdias MVS is supposed to choose the lowest version that satisfies everyone's requirements, so adding a new dep shouldn't cause a downgrade. The transient dep is either upgraded if needed, or left alone if it's already sufficient. *Unless* we're talking about different major versions here, which Go treats as essentially different modules, in which case what's happening isn't a *downgrade*, it's a parallel install of both.